# How to left merge two dataframes with nan without changing types from integer to float types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge two pandas dataframes (df1 and df2) by a key on a specific column, but I want to keep the rows that do not have matching keys on both dfs. In the end I want a df3 with missing values for that key column. When I do that with the following code, my integers are converted into float type:

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how= 'left', on=['Species Name'])

I'm able to convert them to int64 with:

df3['Species ID'] = df3['Species ID'].astype('Int64')

but then my NaNs get converted to '< NA >' which is a 'pandas._libs.missing.NAType'. This is a problem because I want to insert df3 into a postgresql database using psycopg2 and it does not accept Nas like this. Does anyone know how to properly merge those dfs or how to fix the floats without messing with the Na format?

df1:

| Sample ID | Species Name |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| B | Y |
| C | NaN |

df2:

| Species Name | Species ID |
| --- | --- |
| X | 1 |
| Y | 2 |

What I end up with:

| Sample ID | Species Name | Species ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1.000 |
| B | Y | 2.000 |
| C | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.IntXDtype` as dtype of `Species ID` column:

```
df2['Species ID'] = df2['Species ID'].astype(pd.Int8Dtype())
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how= 'left', on=['Species Name'])
print(df3)

# Output
  Sample ID Species Name  Species ID
0         A            X           1
1         B            Y           2
2         C          NaN        <NA>
```

More information: [Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 
I got the following errror. TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent int64 to int8. Either ways. If I end up with NaN in the '< NaN >' as you mentioned won't I run into the same problem I was having before when I was exporting to postgres?

Comment: I was able to make it work using :

df2['Species ID'] = df2['Species ID'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())

However when exporting it to the database I get:
Data could not be inserted! can't adapt type 'NAType'

I need missing information to be as NaN and not < NA >

Comment: Try to modify `pd.NA` by None: `.replace({'Species ID': {pd.NA: None}})`

Comment: Thanks Corralien, this works! I also found a second alternative which works fine:

df3.astype(object).where(pd.notnull(df3), None)