# Why does pandas.DataFrame.merge return dataframes with different column types than the input dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Slightly expanding the [Example 1: Merge on Multiple Columns with Different Names](https://www.statology.org/pandas-merge-multiple-columns/#:%7E:text=Example%201%3A%20Merge%20on%20Multiple%20Columns%20with%20Different%20Names), results in the following Python code using Pandas [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge):

```py
# Create and view first DataFrame:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a1': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
                    'b': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                    'c': [11, 8, 10, 6, 6]})

print(df1)
print(df1.dtypes)
print()

# Create and view second DataFrame:
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a2': [0, 1, 1, 1, 3],
                    'b': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                    'd': [22, 24, 25, 33, 37]})
print(df2)
print(df2.dtypes)
print()

# Merge df1 and df2:
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['a1', 'b'], right_on=['a2', 'b'])
print(df_merge)
print(df_merge.dtypes)
```

The resulting output (I've added line numbers):

```
 1         a1  b   c
 2      0   0  0  11
 3      1   0  0   8
 4      2   1  1  10
 5      3   1  1   6
 6      4   2  1   6
 7      a1    int64
 8      b     int64
 9      c     int64
10      dtype: object
11      
12         a2  b   d
13      0   0  0  22
14      1   1  0  24
15      2   1  0  25
16      3   1  1  33
17      4   3  1  37
18      a2    int64
19      b     int64
20      d     int64
21      dtype: object
22      
23         a1  b   c         a2          d
24      0   0  0  11       0.00      22.00
25      1   0  0   8       0.00      22.00
26      2   1  1  10       1.00      33.00
27      3   1  1   6       1.00      33.00
28      4   2  1   6        NaN        NaN
29      a1      int64
30      b       int64
31      c       int64
32      a2    float64
33      d     float64
34      dtype: object
```

Notice the type of `a2` and `d` columns in the resulting `df_merge` dataframe on lines 24 through 27 have changed from the original `int64` to `float64`.  Why would it need to change the types?

Even the example in the manual at [df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='a')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#:%7E:text=df1.merge(df2%2C%20how%3D%27left%27%2C%20on%3D%27a%27)) shows a `3.0` where I would have expected it to stay an `int64`:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='a')
      a  b  c
0   foo  1  3.0
1   bar  2  NaN
```

But it doesn't explain why.  I see [How to left merge two dataframes with nan without changing types from integer to float types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70507961/how-to-left-merge-two-dataframes-with-nan-without-changing-types-from-integer-to) indicates that `NaN`'s seem to be a factor, but doesn't answer my specific question here as to why the type conversion happens.

If I change `df1` to remove the last row:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a1': [0,  0,  1, 1, ],
                    'b':  [0,  0,  1, 1, ],
                    'c':  [11, 8, 10, 6, ]})
```

Then the output becomes what I would expect:

```
   a1  b   c  a2   d
0   0  0  11   0  22
1   0  0   8   0  22
2   1  1  10   1  33
3   1  1   6   1  33
a1    int64
b     int64
c     int64
a2    int64
d     int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that `NaN` is of type float.

```
import numpy as np

print(type(np.nan))
<class 'float'>
```

There are good reasons why this is the case which I can explain in comments if needed.

So when you do the merge and there are missing values filled with `NaN` then the column type will be automatically changed to `float`. This is because all rows of that column must be of the same data type.

If you specifically wanted to have `int` after the merge then you'd need to use the `fillna` method and define what integers should replace the missing values. E.g. people sometimes use -1 for counts. A simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, np.nan, 5],
    'b': [1, np.nan, 3, 4, 5]
})
df = df.fillna(value=-1).astype(int)

print(df.dtypes)
```

Result is:

```
a    int64
b    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes, this is the answer that makes most sense to me. However, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73637959/257924 answer is also helpful because of the reference to using `dtype=pd.Int64Dtype()` in case it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be legacy where `NaNs` could be only part of type `float`. And pandas does an explicit conversion of the dataframe.

*e.g.* if you have have a dataframe like below :

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a1': [0,  0,  1, np.NaN ]})
>>> df1.astype(int)
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

However with `v0.24`, if you use explicit `dtype=pd.Int64Dtype()`, it is now possible to hold `NaNs` in integers.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a1': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
                    'b': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                    'c': [11, 8, 10, 6, 6]}, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a2': [0, 1, 1, 1, 3],
                    'b': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                    'd': [22, 24, 25, 33, 37]}, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
>>> df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['a1', 'b'], right_on=['a2', 'b'])
>>> df_merge

    a1  b   c   a2  d
0   0   0   11  0   22
1   0   0   8   0   22
2   1   1   10  1   33
3   1   1   6   1   33
4   2   1   6   <NA>    <NA>
```

Note the values are still integers and `NaN` is now `<NA>`

Comment: This is quite helpful. However, "[This is because all rows of that column must be of the same data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73637570/why-does-pandas-dataframe-merge-return-dataframes-with-different-column-types-th/73637959#73637959:~:text=This%20is%20because%20all%20rows%20of%20that%20column%20must%20be%20of%20the%20same%20data%20type.)", in [Michal Racko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73637845/257924)'s answer, combined with `NaN` is representable in type `float`, is what makes the most sense to me. Thus, I'm going to choose his answer as the answer.

Comment: As I read your question was - `why the type conversion happens?` And I think my answer answers that because legacy `NaNs` can only be type `float`. However,  this might sound difficult to many people - why (like your question)? Therefore, I also mention that with recent developments, `NaNs` are also included in `Int` types (notice the capital I) as `NAs`, so that there is no automatic conversion of data types to include `NaNs`

Comment: Agreed. I was ambivalent about given the other person "the answer" status, which is why I posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73637570/why-does-pandas-dataframe-merge-return-dataframes-with-different-column-types-th/73637959?noredirect=1#comment130069521_73637845) on that answer to lead them back to your answer.  Both answers are helpful.